# Leveraging browser caching issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Expires Headers - 2678400s = 31 days 
<ifmodule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2678400 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 750000 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds" 
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds" 
</ifmodule> 

# Cache Headers 
<ifmodule mod_headers.c> 
  # Cache specified files for 31 days 
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$"> 
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public" 
  </filesmatch> 
  # Cache HTML files for a couple hours 
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$"> 
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate" 
  </filesmatch> 
  # Cache PDFs for a day 
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$"> 
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public" 
  </filesmatch> 
  # Cache Javascripts for 31 days 
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$"> 
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private" 
  </filesmatch> 
</ifmodule>
```

www.gtmetrix.com accept my leverage browser cache, but google page speed does not accept that files :

```
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js (30 dakika)
https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js (30 dakika)
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (60 dakika)
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js (60 dakika)
https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 dakika)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 saat)
```

How to fix this problem. I tried cache plugins like super cache, total cache, fast cache. But those are decrease my google page speed score. Now my google page speed score is 87/100 and gtmetrix 93/100.

My web site is :
www.guzellikperisi.com

Comment: Those aren't your files. You can't affect them.

Comment: so what is your suggestion ?

Comment: My suggestion is you don't worry about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those scripts are off server, so your .htaccess file does not apply to them - not much you can do.

To be honest, I only use page speeds as suggestions. I never fully rely on page scores. Even if you look at big sites like ign.com or newyorktimes.com they don't have great scores.

Pick and choose what you want to improve. Yes it's good to strive for perfection, but it just depends on your site.

Comment: so are there any way to fix it?

Comment: There's nothing to really fix. It's not *wrong* in any way. They are off your server, therefor you cannot cache them. It's an external source you're pulling in from somewhere else - and is something you wouldn't want to cache anyway. These page metric sites just look at file types and know that .js can be cached, so tell you to do it. They are just suggestions.